# How to add file name to (beginning of) a text file?

Tags: powershell

For over 800 files I need information that's in the file name to be included in the contents of the text file (actually .md files).

The file names are always of the same structure, something like `0000-title-text-1-23.md`; only the `1-23` part changes (and that is the information I need).

I am a novice as it comes to scripting, but I figured out that this should be an easy task for PowerShell — yet I don't get it working the way I want. What did come closest:

```bsh
Get-Childitem "C:\PATH\*.md" | ForEach-Object{
   $fileName = $_.BaseName
   Add-Content -Path .\*.md -Value $fileName
   }
```

But that adds all file names in the directory, not just the one from the file itself.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are close. Use `$_` is your .md-file. You can use it in `Add-Content` to specify the file wich should get the content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code to do what you exactly want,

- it will get the last 2 parts of your filename and
- put it in the beginning of your file content.

```
Get-Childitem "C:\PATH\*.md" | ForEach-Object{
   $fileNameParts = ($_.BaseName).split('-')
   $info = $fileNameParts[-2] + '-' + $fileNameParts[-1]
   $info + (Get-Content $_ -Raw) | Set-Content $_
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work although it does add the content to the end of the file:

```
#Get all the .txt or .md files in your location
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.txt" | Foreach-Object{

    #Get the base name of the file
    $baseName = $_.BaseName

    #Split the base name
    $array = $baseName -Split '-'

    #Put the third and fourth element in the array into a separate variable
    #This will be added to the file
    $addToFile = $array[3] + '-' + $array[4]

    #Add the $addToFile variable to the file
    Add-Content $_.FullName -Value $addToFile
}
```

Comment: There is a typo in the code: it says "Filer" instead of "File". But even with that one corrected I get no result (there appears nothing new at the end of the file).

Comment: @Jopie Sorry for the typo, corrected :) Have you changed the .txt filter otherwise it won't run on your .md files?

Comment: Good point, I did forget that indeed. Now it works! (Though Shadowfax’s solution still suits my case better. Thanks nevertheless for the more explanatory code — it helps me on my quest of mastering PowerShell!)

Comment: @Jopie Agreed, Shadowfax gave the better-suited answer :) Happy questing!